# How document level locking faster than database level locking?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, performance, database

For example if my disk can write maximum 50Mb/s. I use 100 clients to randomly write 100Mb of data into every collections. (only primary index _id used). People tell me that, if I use document level locking, I will get the job done faster.

what make document level locking level faster than database level locking ?

*to me the disk look very alike nodejs event loop, you handle the job concurrently or one by one, you end up at same amount of time to solve all of them*

Comment: Mostly since you won't use 50mb/s per client per query are you?

Comment: @Sammaye I don't really understand what you mean but at a specific time,  the hard disk is only working with one client, and no matter the query size, the client do use 50Mb/s, right ?

Comment: Basically unless a single client is using 50mb/s for the duration of their lock a single database lock will queue other ops while wasting resources. A collection/document level lock allows for multiple ops to access the database at the same time

Comment: Essentially, using one of your tags: a database level lock would basically make your database single threaded to all users . Of course MongoDB has other concurrency rules as well, hence why they avoided complex locks at first but this is a very very very basic summary

Comment: sorry but I still don't get you, in my example, all 100 clients do is writing and the disk is single thread (at least you can't do parallel writing in HDD) so isn't database level locking is the same as document level locking ?